# using DateTime and Stopwatch to calculate velocity with kinect sdk

Tags: kinect

i'm stuck for days to calculate the velocity of a mouvement so i'll try to more explain my problem.

i have to applicate an approache which allows to detect fall with kinect SDK and VS c#.

this approche takes as input 3 dimensions of a 3Box, built from the coordinates of skeleton joints.

these dimensions are:

W = |xMin - xMax|;

H = |yMin - yMax|;

D = |zMin - zMax|;

with xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, zMin, zMax the minimum and the maximum of coordinates in all the tracked joints.

At this point, this is not the problem.. i already calculated all these values:

```
 List<Joint> JointList = new List<Joint>();
    List<double> JCx = new List<double>();
    List<double> JCy = new List<double>();
    List<double> JCz = new List<double>();
```

// define the min and max of coordinates as the filed of view of kinect

```
    private double xMin = 2.2;
    private double xMax = -2.2;
    private int framecounter = 0;
    private double yMin = 1.6;
    private double yMax = -1.6;
    private double zMin = 4;
    private double zMax = 0;

Skeleton first = GetFirstSkeleton(allFramesReadyEventArgs);


        if (first == null) // if no skeleton
        {
            txtP.Text = "No One"; 
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            txtP.Text = "Yes";
            skeletonDetected = true;


            /// define all joints

            Joint Head = first.Joints[JointType.Head];
            JointList.Add(Head);
            Joint SC = first.Joints[JointType.ShoulderCenter];
            JointList.Add(SC);
            Joint SL = first.Joints[JointType.ShoulderLeft];
            JointList.Add(SL);
            Joint SR = first.Joints[JointType.ShoulderRight];
            JointList.Add(SR);
            Joint EL = first.Joints[JointType.ElbowLeft];
            JointList.Add(EL);
            Joint ER = first.Joints[JointType.ElbowRight];
            JointList.Add(ER);
            Joint WL = first.Joints[JointType.WristLeft];
            JointList.Add(WL);
            Joint WR = first.Joints[JointType.WristRight];
            JointList.Add(WR);
            Joint HandL = first.Joints[JointType.HandLeft];
            JointList.Add(HandL);
            Joint HandR = first.Joints[JointType.HandRight];
            JointList.Add(HandR);
            Joint Spine = first.Joints[JointType.Spine];
            JointList.Add(Spine);
            Joint HipC = first.Joints[JointType.HipCenter];
            JointList.Add(HipC);
            Joint HipL = first.Joints[JointType.HipLeft];
            JointList.Add(HipL);
            Joint HipR = first.Joints[JointType.HipRight];
            JointList.Add(HipR);
            Joint KL = first.Joints[JointType.KneeLeft];
            JointList.Add(KL);
            Joint KR = first.Joints[JointType.KneeRight];
            JointList.Add(KR);
            Joint AnkL = first.Joints[JointType.AnkleLeft];
            JointList.Add(AnkL);
            Joint AnkR = first.Joints[JointType.AnkleRight];
            JointList.Add(AnkR);
            Joint FL = first.Joints[JointType.FootLeft];
            JointList.Add(FL);
            Joint FR = first.Joints[JointType.FootRight];
            JointList.Add(FR);
```

// calculate x, y and z coordinates for each joint and 
// put it into 3 different lists

```
            foreach (Joint j in JointList)
            {
                if (j.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)

                jx = j.Position.X;
                JCx.Add(jx);
                jy = j.Position.Y;
                JCy.Add(jy);
                jz = j.Position.Z;              
                JCz.Add(jz);

                foreach (double f in JCx)
                {

                    if (f < xMin)
                        xMin = f;
                    else if (f > xMax)
                        xMax = f;
                }

                foreach (double f in JCy)
                {


                    if (f < yMin)
                        yMin = f;
                    else if (f > yMax)
                        yMax = f;
                }

                foreach (double f in JCz)
                {

                    if (f < zMin)
                        zMin = f;
                    else if (f > zMax)
                        zMax = f;

                }


            }
            txtminx.Text = xMin.ToString();
            txtmaxx.Text = xMax.ToString();
            txtminy.Text = yMin.ToString();
            txtmaxy.Text = yMax.ToString();
            txtminz.Text = zMin.ToString();
            txtmaxz.Text = zMax.ToString();
```

//calculate the 3 dimensions of the Box and the diagonal WD

```
            double W = System.Math.Abs(xMin - xMax);
            double H = System.Math.Abs(yMin - yMax);
            double D = System.Math.Abs(zMin - zMax);
            double WD = System.Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(W0, 2) + Math.Pow(D0, 2));
```

The problem is when i have to calculate the velocity of the box dimensions vH and vWD .

vH = (Hi - H0) /(Ti- T0);

vWD = (WDi- WD0) /(Ti-T0);

i tried to use DateTime.UtcNow and Stopwatch to calculate the time spend

```
   DateTime T0 = DateTime.UtcNow;

Stopwatch _stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
DateTime Ti = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

but i don't know how to get H value in a first time and in a second also  i'm not sure if this methode will give me real result.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in an application.
I started a StopWatch when the application started:

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
int msNow;
int msPast;
int dif;
TimeSpan currentTime;
TimeSpan lastTime = new TimeSpan(0);
public GaitAnalyzer()
{
        stopWatch.Start();
}
```

Then you just have to do something like this:

```
currentTime = stopWatch.Elapsed;
msNow = currentTime.Seconds * 1000 + currentTime.Milliseconds;
if(lastTime.Ticks != 0)
{
     msPast = lastTime.Seconds * 1000 + lastTime.Milliseconds;
     dif = msNow - msPast;    
}
lastTime = currentTime;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Florent,

some people said that as long as i'm tracking the object per frame, i just need to subtract the timestamps to determine the delta T using AllFrameReady callback or polling. 

i'm a little be confused about what to use. 
i think i'll try both two solutions and tell you if it works.

Comment: can you just telle me how did you define lastTime ?